# Efficiently bitshifting bytes in 32/64 bit quantities?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

For simplicity, assume I'm using a 32 bit little-endian processor and have declared the following 4-byte buffer:

```
unsigned char buffer[] = { 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x46 };
```

Let's say my goal is to bit-wise left shift each byte in the buffer by 4 bits.  That is, I want to transform the buffer values to be: 
`{ 0xbc, 0xde, 0xf4, 0x60 }`.  To perform such a transformation, one might write code like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
  buffer[i] <<= 4; 
  buffer[i] |= (buffer[i + 1] >> 4);
}
buffer[3] <<= 4;
```

While this works, I'd much rather shift all 4 bytes simultaneously using my processor's native 32-bit registers:

```
unsigned char buffer[] = { 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x46 };
unsigned int *p = (unsigned int*)buffer; // unsigned int is 32 bit on my platform
*p <<= 4;
```

The above snippet successfully performs a shift, but not in the way I'm looking for.  It appears that since I'm casting buffer to an unsigned int, the register is loaded (little-endian) with the value `0x46efcdab` (instead of `0xabcdef46`).  Consequently, performing the 4-bit left shift results in `0xb0dafc6e` instead of `0xbcdef460`.

Aside from swapping bytes before the shift (e.g. `htonl` et al.) are there any tricks for efficiently shifting bytes in the manner I am seeking?

Thank you in advance for your insights.

Comment: @user3386109, yes it is x86

Comment: Then I agree with nneonneo's answer. The compiler will implement `htonl` as a single instruction (at the proper optimization level). Not sure what the minimum is, but `-O3` definitely works.

Comment: If you'd used the fixed with types C provides, you could have spared the whole bunch of assumptions how wide `unsigned` is on your platform, etc. See `stdint.h`, that's what they are for. And if you want to serialise data, use proper bitshifting/masking, not casting, your code invokes undefined behaviour..

Comment: @Olaf, can you elaborate on how my code invokes undefined behavior?

Comment: For a starter it has potential for aalignment issues. And you violate effective type rule (aka strict aliasing).

Comment: @Olaf, thanks. I was aware of the alignment issues, but this is the first I had heard of the strict aliasing rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `htonl`/`ntohl` to flip between *network* (big-endian) byte order and *native* byte order:

```
uint32_t *p = (uint32_t*)buffer;
*p = htonl(ntohl(*p) << 4);
```

In effect, this loads the buffer contents as an integer in big-endian order, performs the shift, then writes it back in big-endian order.

This compiles into a couple of `bswap` instructions on x86, so it should be reasonably efficient (`gcc -O3`).

---

Here's some test code (`buffer` is global to avoid constant-folding, and the `return` prevents dead-code elimination):

```
#include <stdint.h>    // uint32_t
#include <arpa/inet.h> // ntohl, htonl

unsigned char buffer[] = { 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x46 };

int main() {
    uint32_t *p = (uint32_t*)buffer; // unsigned int is 32 bit on my platform
    *p = htonl(ntohl(*p) << 4);
    return *p;
}
```

This compiles into the following fairly simple machine code (x86-64; LLVM 7.0.2; `cc -O2`):

```
0000000000000000    pushq   %rbp           ; frame setup
0000000000000001    movq    %rsp, %rbp     ; frame setup
0000000000000004    movl    (%rip), %eax   ; load buffer
000000000000000a    bswapl  %eax           ; endian flip
000000000000000c    shll    $0x4, %eax     ; shift
000000000000000f    bswapl  %eax           ; endian flip
0000000000000011    movl    %eax, (%rip)   ; save buffer
0000000000000017    popq    %rbp           ; finish
0000000000000018    retq
```

Comment: with high enough `march` option (like atom or haswell) it'll emit `movbe` instead of `mov+bswap`

Comment: thanks for pointing out that htonl/ntohl don't actually invoke call instructions

Answer (score 3):

Just for comparison, you can do this without the use of `htonl`/`ntohl`. This assumes a little-endian CPU:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void lshift(unsigned char* buf) {
  uint32_t* p = (uint32_t*)buf;
  uint32_t lo = *p & 0x0F0F0F0F;
  uint32_t hi = *p & 0xF0F0F000;
  *p = (lo << 4) | (hi >> 12);
}
```

And the generated assembly with `gcc -O3`:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
movl    (%rdi), %eax
movl    %eax, %ecx
shll    $4, %ecx
andl    $-252645136, %ecx       ## imm = 0xFFFFFFFFF0F0F0F0
shrl    $12, %eax
andl    $986895, %eax           ## imm = 0xF0F0F
orl     %ecx, %eax
movl    %eax, (%rdi)
popq    %rbp
retq
```

Depending on how many cycles `bswapl` is, it's likely the faster alternative.

Comment: thanks for posting a solution that only uses bitwise operators